# Is it possible to add subcommands to NPM?

Tags: node.js, npm

I was wondering if I could create a package that extends NPM and adds a new subcommand. I would like to create something like `npm pretty` what would order my package.json keys in a specific order.

- I know it's kind of possible with npm scripts but I want to have it as a subcommand to use it globally.
- I know there is https://github.com/keithamus/sort-package-json but I want to extend this project to my needs.

Comment: Why do you want it to be an npm subcommand vs just an executable script?

Comment: @Paul cause it is easier to remember and looks better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm able to discover, you have two options.

The first is to add to the scripts key of your project's package.json file:

```
"scripts" : {
    "pretty": "some-command-to-run [args]"
}
```

To run that, you'll use `npm run pretty`.  Which isn't exactly like you want, but it's what's offered.

I had thought there's some form of global package.json file, but I'm not able to find any documentation around that so I'm taking absence of documentation as documentation of absence.

This means your only other option would be to contribute back to the [npm source](https://github.com/npm/cli) as a pull request, and hopefully they bring it into the baseline.

Comment: Hm, yes, I had hoped there is something like this already... anyway thanks!